# Глюк в хроме, при наведении мышкой на строку в таблице

Tags: css

При наведении мышкой, часть данных исчезает, в фоксе такой проблемы не замечали.

пример смотрите здесь http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vyNewj
[image: problem]

```js
var documentWidth = $(window).width();
$('table').on('mouseover', 'tr.filteredTable', function(){
    var tableWidth = $(this).width();
    var scaleFactor = 1;
    if(documentWidth/2 >= tableWidth) {
        documentWidth = documentWidth/2;
    }
    for(var i = 1.4;i >= scaleFactor;i-=0.1) {
        if(i.toFixed(1)*tableWidth > documentWidth)continue;
        scaleFactor = i.toFixed(1);
    }
    $(this).css({
        'position': 'relative',
        'width': $(this).clientWidth * scaleFactor + "px",
        'height': $(this).clientHeight * scaleFactor + "px",
        '-webkit-transform': 'scale('+scaleFactor+')',
        '-moz-transform': 'scale('+scaleFactor+')',
        '-ms-transform': 'scale('+scaleFactor+')',
        '-o-transform': 'scale('+scaleFactor+')',
        'transform': 'scale('+scaleFactor+')'
    });
})
$('table').on('mouseleave', 'tr.filteredTable', function(){
    $(this).css({
        'position': 'static',
        '-webkit-transform': 'scale(1)',
        '-moz-transform': 'scale(1)',
        '-ms-transform': 'scale(1)',
        '-o-transform': 'scale(1)',
        'transform': 'scale(1)'
    });
})
```

```css
tr { box-shadow:rgb(153, 153, 153) 0px 0px 5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;">
<table class="bordered relative product-list exchange_list">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>col</th>
        <th class="center">col</th>
        <th class="center">col.</th>
        <th class="center"><a href="#">col. <i class="fa fa-sort-numeric-asc"></i></a></th>
        <!--th class="center">ед изм.</th-->
        <th class="center"><a href="#">col <i class="fa fa-sort-numeric-asc"></i></a></th>
        <th class="center">col</th>
        <th class="center">col</th>
        <th class="center">col</th>
        <th class="center">col</th>
        <th class="center">col</th>
        <th class="center">col</th>
        <th class="center"></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody><tr class="filteredTable"><td><img src="http://000-1.ru/images/1476527742-5906.jpg" class="responsive-img" width="100"></td><td><a data-name="title" href="/product/12.33">NAME</a><br><div class="chip tag">text.</div></td><td class="center">№37</td><td class="center">5.00</td><td data-name="price" class="center">2500.00</td><td data-name="count" class="center">1000</td><td class="center">500</td><td class="center">25</td><td data-name="status" class="center"><i class="fa fa fa-check-circle-o fir" aria-hidden="true"><span style="font-size:0.001px">0</span></i></td><td class="center"><i class="fa fa-ban grey-text"></i></td><td class="center">USA</td><td class="center">NEW-YORK</td><td class="center"><a href="/product/12.33" type="button" data-p="" data-t="0" class="btn btn-flat btn-more right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Переведите на русский, чтобы получить ответ.

Comment: Нет проблем, готово.